# Image from Picturebox to another Picturebox

Tags: sql, vb.net

I've created a system which is Monitoring System using Plug and Play USB port Barcode Scanner that will scan id numbers. (When I plug my scanner and it just scanned the barcode the display the code).  Put their information in every panel. As shown in the image [image: Image From Left to Right]

How can I move the First image(Left Image) from the First Picturebox to the second Picturebox(Center Image) and the second Picturebox image to the third Picturebox(Right Image). It serves as the two images (from the center to the right) are the recent record of the any individual.

This is my code: Adodb with SQL

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        TextBoxIDNumberIn.Text = TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text
        Try
            Connection()
            sql = "Select * from Info where ID_Number like '" + TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text + "'"
            rs.Open(sql, conn)
            If rs.Fields(0).Value = TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text Then
                TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text = rs.Fields(0).Value
                textboxCategoryTriggers.Text = rs.Fields(1).Value
                TextBoxNameTrigger.Text = rs.Fields(3).Value + " " + rs.Fields(4).Value + ". " + rs.Fields(2).Value
                textboxImageLocation.Text = rs.Fields(12).Value.ToString
                Try
                    Connection1()
                    sql1 = "Select * from allthisTime where idnumber like '" + TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text + "' and timeout like '" + "Not Yet" + "' and datesss like '" + Date.Today + "'"
                    rs1.Open(sql1, conn1, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
                    rs1.Update()
                    rs1.Fields(2).Value = TimeOfDay
                    rs1.UpdateBatch()
                    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = textboxImageLocation.Text
                    textboxCategory1.Text = textboxCategoryTriggers.Text
                    textboxIDNumber1.Text = TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text
                    textboxName1.Text = TextBoxNameTrigger.Text
                    TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text = ""
                    textboxTime1.Text = "Time Out"
                    conn1.Close()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    conn1.Close()
                    Connection1()
                    sql1 = "Select * from allthisTime"
                    rs1.Open(sql1, conn1, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
                    rs1.AddNew()
                    rs1.Fields(0).Value = TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text
                    rs1.Fields(1).Value = TimeOfDay
                    rs1.Fields(2).Value = "Not Yet"
                    rs1.Fields(3).Value = Date.Today
                    rs1.Update()

                    PictureBox1.ImageLocation = textboxImageLocation.Text
                    textboxCategory1.Text = textboxCategoryTriggers.Text
                    textboxIDNumber1.Text = TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text
                    textboxName1.Text = TextBoxNameTrigger.Text
                    TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text = ""
                    textboxTime1.Text = "Time In"
                    conn1.Close()
                End Try
                conn.Close()
            End If
            TimeIn()
        Catch ex1 As Exception
            MsgBox("ID Number doesn't exists. Please contact system administrator.")
            TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text = ""
            conn.Close()
        Finally
            TimeIn()
        End Try
        'conn.Close()
        TextBoxIDNumberTrigger.Text = ""
        PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image
        PictureBox3.Image = PictureBox2.Image

    End Sub
```

Comment: Please define: "**Scan**"

Comment: Also, is this [tag:vba] (with [tag:ms-access]), or [tag:vb.net] (which is unrelated to [tag:ms-access])?

Comment: This is vb.net with ms-access sir. What do you mean by "Scan" sir?

Comment: This is vb.net with ms-access database, I' using Access (2002-2003 format).mdb as my database. What do you mean by defining "Scan" sir?

Comment: I have to ask: which part are you "new" to?  If I understand correctly, you've designed `.NET` applications but this is your 1st time connecting to an Access Database via `.NET`?  Is your application functioning properly outside of having to connect to Access?

Comment: And I mean "scan?" as in, how does this `system which is monitoring system that will scan id numbers` ***scan*** these photos?  With a flatbed scanner?  A webcam?  Barcode reader?  I don't understand what you're doing or why.  Here are some [great tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: I'm new to connecting .net applications. Yes sir, I've designed .NET applications. Yes, my application is properly functioning. With connecting to the access. I tried any solution that I can come up but doesn't work. I tried searching for solutions but doesn't match also what I need.

Comment: I used plug and play barcode scanner in my system sir.

Comment: Ok my apologies (it's not uncommon for new users to confuse VBA vs VB.NET.)    Okay, a barcode reader.   Which kind of output?  "Keyboard Wedge" output, RS232 serial output, USB output, something else?  ([More info](http://www.taltech.com/barcodesoftware/articles/which_barcode_scanner_interface))

Comment: You don't need to call anyone here "Sir". But to read [the "tips" link](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) I posted earlier? After 45mins I'm still not clear on what you're trying to do, and I'm out of time, but I would suggest you read that link, as well as each of these ones: {  [help/on-topic], the [tour],[mcve], [ask] }, and then you can [edit] your question to provide more information about **what** you're trying to do, **which** kind of scanner you're using, **why** you need to do this, *how* you've tried to do it so far (with >1 link).

Comment: My apologies but I'm also confused about the meaning of the USB output of the link you given. But when I scanned any barcode I get the code. I didn't set any of its settings.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you want to _"move the First image(Left Image) from the First Picturebox to the second Picturebox(Center Image)"_? Do you want to _**remove**_ it from the first picture box, then _**add**_ it to the second?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove it from the first picturebox then add it to the second, because another picture will occur in the first picturebox and if there's another picture box the image will forwarded to the next picturebox.

Comment: PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image.  Easy peasy.

Comment: @HansPassant I've already tried that method. But it doesn't work. Because after I scanned ID numbers the two Picture boxes or three picture boxes always stay the same. As you can see from the image above.

Comment: It works.  What "doesn't work" could possibly mean is very hard to guess when you don't post code.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @HansPassant My apologies for saying that it doesn't work. The truth is I've already tried it. See my code above. If you think that I'm missing something in my code. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You need to assign PictureBox2.Image *before* you give PictureBox1 a new image.  Doing it afterwards does indeed give them all the same image.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm really confused in my mind that "If I scanned Barcode then the picture goes to the Picturebox1. But when I scanned again. I want that the image in the PictureBox1 will go to PictureBox2 and PictureBox1 replaces by another pictures. Same up to PictureBox3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165339/discussion-between-j-leo-and-hans-passant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you need to pass your PictureBox1 image to PictureBox2 and old PictureBox2 to PictureBox3.

If yes so you just need to use this code (if you PictureBox1 already have image and image show without problem in first place) :

```
PictureBox3.ImageLocation = PictureBox2.ImageLocation
PictureBox2.ImageLocation = PictureBox1.ImageLocation
```